# Modify activity after clicking on a notification

Tags: android

I have a normal notification system that looks like this:

```
Notification notification new Notification(
        R.drawable.alerts_notification,
        alertTitle,
        System.currentTimeMillis());
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MyActivity.class);
intent.setAction(MyActivity.ONE_ACTION);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, intent, 0);
mNotifMan.notify(ID, notification);
```

Notice that I'm using `ONE_ACTION` as the action of the intent. What I do is verify the action on the activity and select one of the tabs (it's a `TabActivity`).

All that works fine if the activity is closed, because the `Intent` will open the activity and then I will decide what to do depending on the action in the `Intent`. But, if the activity is already opened, it launches a new activity. On the other hand, if I add the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`, the activity is not launched twice but I can't the tab is not chosen either.

So, how can choose a tab by clicking on the notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found how to do it... it seems I hadn misread the documentation. What I did was:

1. Add this to the activity in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file: `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`
2. Overwrite the `onNewIntent(Intent intent)` method on the activity and put there all the logic to select the tabs etc.
3. Launch the intent with the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT`

@schwiz, thanks for your answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Have your intent open your tab activity and put an extra in it denoting the tab.  When you detect action resume get a handle on your tab controller and change the tab through code.